# Javascript Function being triggered by onClick check

Tags: javascript, triggers, onclick

I was wondering if there is a way for a function to check if it was triggered by the onClick method?

```
function check(id) {
   if(onClick()) {
     alert('thanks for clicking!');
   }
}
```

I've tried to find this but I can't seem to come across anything.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will give the type of event occured. Then you can match whether it was click or mousemove or mousedown or anything

```
<body onclick="eventType(event)">

function eventType(event)
{ 
   alert(event.type); // if you want to check for click then use if(event.type=='click')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your function is used a callback for an event somewhere, it will get the event object as an argument. So you simple check if event.type is "click".

```
function check(e) {
    if (e.type == "click") {
        alert("Thanks for clicking me!");
    }
}

var button = document.getElementById("a_button");
button.onclick = check;
```